# PowerPoint VBA - Auto Run a button in slide when opening slide in SlideShow mode

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I've a button created in a specific slide (example slide number 10) like following:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Label1_Click
End Sub
```

I want to autorun this button when I open this slide in SlideShow mode.
Which command can recall this private button?

In a module I've created

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange()
    Dim i As Long
    i = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.CurrentShowPosition
    Select Case i
        Case 10
            ==> which command can call a specific button action included in a specific slide?
            
        Case 11
            xxxxx
        Case 12
            xxxx
    End Select
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You want to run the macro automatically, not the button. Anything automatic in PowerPoint requires using events. Here's an introduction to events: http://www.rdpslides.com/pptfaq/FAQ00004_Make_your_VBA_code_in_PowerPoint_respond_to_events.htm How to set up an event listener: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=327 A list of events supported in different versions: https://www.officeoneonline.com/vba/events_version.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're over-complicating things. Instead of trying to automatically click a button that invokes code, just invoke the code directly.

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange()
    Dim i As Long
    i = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.CurrentShowPosition
    Select Case i
        Case 10
            ==> which command can call a specific button action included in a specific slide?
' just call the code:
MsgBox "Call the code directly rather that trying to activate a button"
            
        Case 11
            xxxxx
        Case 12
            xxxx
    End Select
    
End Sub
```